# PHP return true if at least one item is in array and one is not

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to return true for this if statement, if at least one item is in array and one not in array and not sure how to write that.

This of course works, but I need to return false if all items are in array or if all items are not in array.

```
$shipping_classes = array( 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300 );
$cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$cart_items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
$items_match = false;

foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item )
    if( in_array( $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class(), $shipping_classes ) && $cart_items_count > 1 || !in_array( $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class(), $shipping_classes ) && $cart_items_count > 1 ) {
        $items_match = true;
        break; // Stop the loop
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean at least 1 item from the `$shipping_class` variable?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes, I need that if $cart_item class matches the one from $shipping_classes array and there is another $cart_item which doesn't match then return true. 
This is working and returns true, but I need if all $cart_item classes match #shipping_classes array then return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the number of times something is found/not found then compare at the end?

```
<?php 
    $shipping_classes = array( 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300 );
    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $cart_items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    $items_match = false;

    $inArray    = 0;
    $notInArray = 0;


    foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item ){
        if( in_array( $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class(), $shipping_classes ) && $cart_items_count > 1 || !in_array( $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class(), $shipping_classes ) && $cart_items_count > 1 ) {
            $inArray++;
        } else { 
            $notInArray++;
        }
    }
    if( ( $cart_items_count == $notInArray ) || ( $cart_items_count == $inArray ) ){
        $items_match = false;
    } else { 
        $items_match = true;
    }
```

Comment: Can't get it working. Now it returns false in all conditions unless I set    $inArray = 1; $notInArray = 0; But then works the same way as my code and returns true even if all items are in array. I need that to be false.

Comment: @Aivaras, to simplify your problem you can treat $cart_items_count <= 1 as a special case (it's always false). Then your if statement looks like `in_array || !in_array´ , which is an obious tautology. Once you fix that (hint:drop the or and everything behind it) and combine it with RossW counting idea, you have your solution.

Comment: @jh1711 Ha yes, my logic didn't made much sense. Got it working.

Answer (score 0):

How about decoupling the code that checks if an array exists or not in another array from the code that builds the arrays? For example:

```
function allOrNoneInArray($search, $array)
{
    $diff  = array_diff($search, $array);
    $ndiff = count($diff);

    return $ndiff === 0 || $ndiff === count($search);
}

$shipping_classes = array(50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300);
$items_shipping_classes = array();
foreach($cart_items as $cart_item) {
    $items_shipping_classes[] = $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class();
}

if (allOrNoneInArray($items_shipping_classes, $shipping_classes)) {
    // add code here
}
```